# android:How to fill two list view of same activity with one adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, custom-adapter

I have two lists & one custom adapter..both lists have same structure

```
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_left_drawer);
mDrawerListBottom = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_left_drawer_bottom);

adapter = new DrawerItemsCustomAdapter(this);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);    
    adapter = new DrawerItemsCustomAdapter(this);
    mDrawerListBottom.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Q: How can I identify which ListView is accessing adapter, how to identify in adapter class.

what is & how to use ?

```
   public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

thanks.

Comment: *how to identify in adapter class* why would you need such information ?

Comment: what do you mean by *identify which ListView is accessing adapter,* you are passing `ArrayList` check it with that

Comment: Why are there two lines that say `adapter = new DrawerItemsCustomAdapter(this);`?

Comment: thanks, i was confused...  adapter object per ListView is perfect answer..thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bad practice to use the same reference of an adapter across two different ListViews because modifying the underlying data would require you to notify both listviews of a change.

So instead of this

```
adapter = new DrawerItemsCustomAdapter(this);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);    
adapter = new DrawerItemsCustomAdapter(this);
mDrawerListBottom.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Simply make two separate adapters.

You can use the same adapter class because, as you said, both lists have the same structure.

```
DrawerItemsCustomAdapter adapter1 = new DrawerItemsCustomAdapter(this);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter1);    
DrawerItemsCustomAdapter adapter2 = new DrawerItemsCustomAdapter(this);
mDrawerListBottom.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

It is not clear where you have initialized the List of data for these adapters, though, since it is not a parameter to the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear. I think you are confused, but correct me if I'm wrong.

You are reusing the same object for creating the adapter for the other ListView, thus overwriting the first. I assume you want to handle them separately so you should use a new object:

```
adapter1 = new DrawerItemsCustomAdapter(this);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter1);    
adapter2 = new DrawerItemsCustomAdapter(this);
mDrawerListBottom.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

Otherwise, there is no way to determine which instance of a ListView is using the Adapter at any time.

You should be using different Adapters for different ListViews. An Adapter should know how to populate a ListView in a single way.

Answer (score 1):

```
            mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_left_drawer);
            mDrawerListBottom = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_left_drawer_bottom);

            adapter = new DrawerItemsCustomAdapter(this);
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);    
            adapter1 = new DrawerItemsCustomAdapter(this);
            mDrawerListBottom.setAdapter(adapter1);

           mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String s = adapter.getItem(position);
                    }
                });
           mDrawerListBottom.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                  String s = adapter1.getItem(position);
                    }
                });
```